# Javers and anonymization

Tags: javers

We are using javers and using some private datas. We must store the changes (for our business needs) on these datas (that's why we do not exclude them).
We have to be able to make these datas anonym. 
Is there a way to anonymize the datas stored in javers ?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `make these datas anonym`?

Comment: We must keep the datas stored in javers (because we will use them later), but we must modify the values for "First name, last name, etc" not to be able to find the original value of these datas. All sthe states and changes of states on name, last name, must be changed

Comment: Are you talking about ciphering?

Comment: It's more like writting random datas in the fields instead of ciphering. I'm sorry my English is really poor.
What we do actually :
- We use JAVERS to audit the changes of objects. Some of these datas are private and we must "clear" them at some point
What we exactly want is :
- To put random data (using faker framework) in the private datas stored by Javers

Comment: it's called obfuscation and javers won't do it. It doesn't make sense. just ignore those fields in your javers mapping